# How do I play an iframe mp4 on click using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Trying to play an mp4 iframe on click of a button, but I don't know how.

I tried the below but didn't work

```js
$(this).find("iframe").trigger("play");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"
allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Could this be a typo: `ElephantsDream.mp`? Shouldn't that be `mp4` at the end? Also show the HTML with the button. It might be `.find` will not work depending on the element hierarchy.

Comment: This won't work - you can't access the Iframe from the parent and vice versa if it is not on the same domain. You would need to run Javascript on both sides and use the message API. But you won't get your Code on the Google Servers. Sorry mate.

Comment: Why an iframe, why are you not using a `video` element for this?

Answer (score 0):

you made a typo when writing the video source, maybe mp4 not just mp.

you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play-video').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    e.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

*in document HTML*

```
<a id="play-video" href="#">Title : Elephants Dream</a><br />
<iframe id="video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My codepen : https://codepen.io/maulanadata/pen/mdKxgme

Comment: This won't work - you can't access the Iframe from the parent and vice versa if it is not the same domain.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).